# Sqlite query aggregating

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions, case-when

I'm looking to solve the following issue using Sqlite3. I would like to aggregate this data:

```
+--------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
| DRAWID | BETID | TICKETID |  STATUS  | AMOUNT |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
|      1 |     1 |        1 | OK       |      3 |
|      1 |     2 |        1 | OK       |      2 |
|      1 |     3 |        2 | CANCELED |      4 |
|      1 |     4 |        2 | CANCELED |      7 |
|      1 |     5 |        3 | OK       |      5 |
|      1 |     6 |        3 | OK       |      4 |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
```

To the following

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| BetsOK | BetsNotOk | TicketsOk | TicketsNotOk | AmountOk | AmountNotOk |
+--------+-----------+-----------+--------------+----------+-------------+
|      4 |         2 |         2 |            1 |       14 |          11 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

To get the right grouping for TicketsOk I seem to be resulting to doing two subqueries and having to join. One subquery for Ok and another for NotOk like this

```
(SELECT drawId, (DISTINCT ticketId) FROM Bets WHERE drawId =  AND userId = AND Status IN ("OK")) TblTicketsOk ...
```

Is there something possibly that exists in sqlite3 or in general sql that would be simpler. Can someone please help in writing the full sql statement to solve this?

Comment: So your just asking for a more efficient way to write your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need use `join`, try to use `distinct` and `CASE WHEN` in `COUNT` function.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'OK' then BETID end)) BetsOK,
       COUNT(distinct(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CANCELED' then BETID end)) BetsNotOk,
       COUNT(distinct(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'OK' then TICKETID  end)) TicketsOk,
       COUNT(distinct(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CANCELED' then TICKETID  end)) TicketsNotOk,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'OK' then AMOUNT else 0 end) AmountOk,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CANCELED' then AMOUNT  else 0 end) AmountNotOk
FROM T
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/985d2/1)

**[Results]**:

```
| BetsOK | BetsNotOk | TicketsOk | TicketsNotOk | AmountOk | AmountNotOk |
|--------|-----------|-----------|--------------|----------|-------------|
|      4 |         2 |         2 |            1 |       14 |          11 |
```

Comment: it's awesome! ps : it can be without `else null` [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8d0af9/17/0)

Comment: @ITWeiHan Yes you are right, because it default have been `NULL` :)